# Reference to Record is ambiguous

Tags: java, jooq, java-17

I've updated the Java runtime that will be used to build my application (from 11 to 17), and the source and target configurations continue to be 11.

After trying to build using the Java 17, I got the following error message:

> reference to Record is ambiguous... both interface org.jooq.Record in
> org.jooq and class java.lang.Record in java.lang match

Does anyone know what's the problem and how to solve it?

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Java type list is ambiguous?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6048946/java-type-list-is-ambiguous) (different class, but essentially the same problem), and [reference to IndexOutOfBoundsException is ambiguous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2834253/reference-to-indexoutofboundsexception-is-ambiguous).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that jOOQ has a class name with the same name that the JDK does, so when you use the * (asterisk) to import the classes from jOOQ, the compiler doesn't know which class you are trying to use, for such cases you will need to import the `org.jooq.Record` explicitly.

Comment: Where does the question mention asterisks?

Comment: Does it need to be mentioned?

Comment: Yes, your question should have a [mre] which shows the problem.

Comment: Folks, don't be so harsh. The question was valid. The same code compiled before and stopped compiling with this error, all the information needed to answer the question has been given.